# Ajax add input more than once

Tags: php, ajax

I've successfully wrote a working Ajax code, but the problem is that i can add an input field only once. I have a submit input, that calls Ajax script, everything works, the input text field appears, but after this if i want to add another text field by clicking on the submit input, it does not work. You only load once (YOLO). How do i write more awesome code that lets me add as many text fields as needed? Thanks for every reply. Here is my code:

index.php:

```
<head>

<script>
function ajaxobj(){

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)    {
        document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }   
}

xmlhttp.open('GET', 'ajaxAddInput.php',true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" onclick="ajaxobj();">
<div id="asd"></div>

</body>
```

the php file:

```
<?php
echo '<input type=\"text\">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a standardized library, just like [jQuery](http://jquery.com). With this in mind, you might use the following code:

```
$("#asd").on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax("ajaxAddInput.php", {input: val});
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the library with classes as well:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax("ajaxAddInput.php", {input: val});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ye i know about jquery, but i heard that i should first learn classic Ajax before jumping into jquery. Is classic Ajax obsolete now?

Comment: While this might be a question of taste, I would prefer solutions that work over something you need to fiddle around with. And why not use a library which takes care of the different browser approaches for you?